# comparing dog pictures

Tags: android, github, image-processing, compare

I am building an android app,
And I want to add the ability that when I take a picture of a dog, I will search in my DB that consist picture of dogs, I want to find the pictures that is the same dog or at least quite similar to him.

Is there any library or github that can be used to compare pictures of dogs?
I'm pretty new at this.

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> You need to use some image processing framework.., Like `opencv` i have used it for detecting the difference in two images and showing rectangle over the difference area. You can also go for google `tensorflow`.

---

Well, if you want to detect images containing dogs, you need a `harcascade` and you have to train it with positive and negative samples, so that it would learn how to find dogs within images. And answer is not so short it is a machine learning library. If you want to detect dogs are present in given image or not , with `c++ and opencv`, i can help by providing sample basic programs too

---

Personally i have used `opencv` it is great fun in learning and there is also very active forum like stackoverflow for them :
[This is the link of opencv forum](http://answers.opencv.org/)

Hope it helps :)

Comment: If you find it helpful, then please let me know and accept it as answer so that it helps another users to find already answered questions. Its good to hear that you are interested in machine learning. Good luck